# Make adfs session cookie persistent after web browser close

Tags: cookies, adfs

I'm facing an issue with CRM 2011 IFD and ADFS:

The problem is that every user is forced to login in CRM again after closing web browser.

Is there any way to make the session cookie persistent even if web browser is closed ?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware there is not a way of doing this, I looked into it about a year ago, you can set the TokenLifeTime in the Web.config, however this is will only work during the browser session.

If you users are logging in via the domain connected computers they should sign in automatically, you should only be presented with this issue on computers that are external or not joined to the domain.

Sorry this doesn't answer your question, but may save you hours of looking for a solution that doesn't appear to exist.

Comment: I'm having the opposite effect. I'm trying to unload the cookie after the browser closes. For some reason it keeps me logged in and I don't want the user to stay logged in.